# How do you run more groupby operations together?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
c=dogs.groupby(by="Dn")[["SP","Fin_binary","won"]].agg({"won":["cumsum"],"SP":["cumsum","cumcount"], "Fin_binary":"cumsum"})

Total_win7 = dogs.groupby(by="Dn")["won"].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(7, 1).sum())
```

I know about setting the dict as the parameter of the aggregate function with which you can run different functions on different columns.

However I can't run a custom function like the one below that uses rolling. Is there anyway to do this.

Is it very computationally expensive to run groupby multiple times?

Comment: Can you post a sample of input data and expected output, please?

Comment: My question does not need sample data. I am asking whether it is possible to run the function in the second line together with the ones in the first.